# Moving v-axis tick labels on combo chart

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

I have a chart that shows the number of visits and ratio of sales / visits. Visits are displayed using columns, while the sales / visits ratio is displayed using a line chart.

I wish to move the ratio labels to the right of the chart. Currently, the volume appears on the right hand, secondary axis.

http://jsfiddle.net/2zcLL/8/ (I can't get it to work in jsfiddle, but works fine locally?)

The issue I am having revolves around how Google requires combo charts to be set up, that is, column data series must come before the line data series to work.

What I required looks something like this:

```
series: {0: {type: "bars", targetAxisIndex:0}, 2: {type: "line", targetAxisIndex:1}},
```

But the above doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, ComboCharts do not require your data series to be in any particular order.  You can put `bars`, `line`, `area`, `steppedArea`, and `candlestick` type series in whatever order you want.

Second, you only have two data series, so the series option should be:

```
series: {0: {type: "bars", targetAxisIndex:0}, 1: {type: "line", targetAxisIndex:1}}
```

Here's an exmple of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/m4qwT/.  Note that I increased the width of the chart to show the axes properly (they don't display at all given the options as you specified them).